# SharePoint 2007 - add additional menu to Global Navigation in a Master Page

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

In the source code for a master page, there is a section that has the following ASP.NET item: . This contains the "Welcome (User Name)" and Site Actions menus.

How do I create an additional menu that is similar to the look and feel of the Welcome menu? I've tried to create Front End HTML that behaves similar to the out of the box SharePoint menus, but it isn't quite right. I would prefer to utilize an ASP.NET or SharePoint control that acts similar to the SharePoint menu if that is possible.

For example, is `<SharePoint:AspMenu>` the appropriate control to use?

Thanks,

Robert

Answer (score 0):

i am sure you will get better answer than this but just wanted to point what i have done to do this

i have added javascript library (JQuery) (for some other reason ) and when time come to do this thing i just added a JQuery code that creates another item in the navigation list with appropriate style and css class  with the needed link and caption.

Answer (score 0):

You could try another instance of the [PersonalActions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.personalactions.aspx) control with a custom GroupId. But when the control is rendered, it might also say "Welcome, [User]" just like the original.